# SVM for regression : confidence intervalls

Tags: r, svm, e1071

I use the svm function (for regression) to make forecast like I would with for exemple the arima function:
`fit<-auto.arima(ts)`
`prediction<-forecast(fit,h=20)`
which returns different attributes :

> 1. `prediction$mean` which is the actual prediction
> 2. `prediction$lower` and `prediction$upper` which are the   **boundaries of the confidence intervals** on each points of the   `prediction$mean`.

I would like the `svm` function (from *e1071* package) to return a more detailed answer than just the value (like the `forecast()` would).
 But I guess it is not implemented in the function yet.
Is there another function to do it ? Or should I use **bootstrap** methods to try to estimate those boundaries? And if I should use this are they pre-implemented version of them instead of using sample over a for loop which is very time-consuming ?